# Updating GCC, received errors during 'make'

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to update GCC on a computer running RHEL6.6-server edition in my lab. I keep receiving errors after running the 'make' command. Here's some of the code:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/./gmp/.libs   /libgmp.a(mp_set_fns.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against        `__gmp_default_allocate' can not be used when making a shared object;     recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/./gmp/.libs/libgmp.a: could not read symbols:  Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[6]: *** [libjavamath.la] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/native/jni/java-math'
make[6]: Entering directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/native/jni'
/bin/sh ../../scripts/check_jni_methods.sh
make[6]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/native/jni'
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/native/jni'
make[5]: Entering directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/native'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/native'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/native'
Making all in resource
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/resource'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/resource'
Making all in scripts
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/scripts'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/scripts'
Making all in tools
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/tools'
make  all-am
make[5]: Entering directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/tools'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/tools'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath/tools'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath'
true  DO=all multi-do # make
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava/classpath'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava'
make[1]: *** [all-target-libjava] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/GCC-5.1.0/gcc-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I saw another question on here where two of the poster's errors were the same ones I have and the answer was to install makeinfo in the texinfo package. I installed that package and the above code is what I received after running the 'make' command again.

I'm not sure what error libjavamath.la is, but I'm assuming it's a file that I need in order to complete 'make.' The other error is all-recursive and I have no clue what it could mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the simple instructions at https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC and unless you actually need the Java compiler you should configure with `--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran` (or whatever set of languages you *do* want, without Java).

libjavamath.la is a library built as part of the GCJ Java compiler, but if you don't care about using GCJ then you can (and IMHO should) configure GCC without it. That will solve any problems that happen when building libjavamath.la, because it won't be built.

Answer (score -2):

I configured as:
./configure --disable-shared --enable-languages=all --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-tls --with-fpmath=sse --disable-multilib --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --with-system-zlib --enable-gnu-unique-object --with-mpc=/usr/local/ --with-java-home=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/ --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-__cxa_atexit

You should try it.

Comment: No, because using `./configure` in the source dir is not supported for GCC. And `--disable-shared` is silly. And half those options are enabled by default anyway.